# How to install kernel 3.9 in Debian Jessie from repos?

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, amd-catalyst

I was wondering if it is possible to install kernel 3.9 in Debian Jessie from repos. A brief check shows that there are only 2.6, 3.2 and 3.13 kernels in repos Compiling my own kernel is the last thing I want to do.

Btw I need kernel 3.9 in order to install Catalyst 3.12, because I am having serious problems with Catalyst 14.3 and I cannot install Catalyst 3.12 on kernels>3.9.

Thank you!

Comment: What issues are you having with Catalyst 14.3 ?

Comment: [This bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1256561)

Comment: Also I have tried to patch Catalyst 13.12 to make it work on kernels>3.9 following several different approaches (e.g. [link](http://henryhermawan.blogspot.com/2014/02/amd-catalyst-patch-for-kernel-313x.html)), but it did not work out.